# Divide by the previous value in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, math

Hey so I have an array that is 16,000 values long, but I'll simplify the problem here. I want to divide each array value by the previous one, and then output it to a new array. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
$close = array(100,101,99,98,99,103,102);
```

Essentially I want it to start at [1] and divide by [0], and then do [2] and divide by [1], and so on, so that I have a new array that is:

```
$new = array(1.01, 0.98, 0.99, 1.01, 1.04, .99);
```

Basically, I am doing this because I want to find %change in a stock's price every day, given the closing prices that I already have.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $close = array(100,101,99,98,99,103,102);
    $new = array();

    foreach($close as $k => $v) {

        if($k == 0)
            continue;

        $new[] = round($close[$k]/$close[$k-1], 2);
    }

    print_r($new);


?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.01
    [1] => 0.98
    [2] => 0.99
    [3] => 1.01
    [4] => 1.04
    [5] => 0.99
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$close = array(100,101,99,98,99,103,102);
$new=array();
for ($i=1; $i <count($close) ; $i++) { 
    $new[]=$close[$i]/$close[$i-1];
    round($new[$i-1],2);
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting ,Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Demo [here](http://ideone.com/RllbDj)

You could do this with a single `for` loop like:

```
$close = array(100,101,99,98,99,103,102);
$new = array();

for ($i=1; $i <count($close) ; $i++) { 
    $val = round($close[$i] / $close[$i-1], 2);
    array_push($new, $val); 

}
var_dump($new);
```

This would give you:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  float(1.01)
  [1]=>
  float(0.98)
  [2]=>
  float(0.99)
  [3]=>
  float(1.01)
  [4]=>
  float(1.04)
  [5]=>
  float(0.99)
}
```

Comment: How about the round function? So that the output is equal to what OP wanted?!

Comment: Yes, added it in there :)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! This would have also worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess below answer will help you:

```
<?php
$array = array(100,101,99,98,99,103,102);
$newArray = array();
$count = count($array);
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++){
    $newArray[] = round($array[$i] / $array[($i - 1)], 2);
}

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Let me know if you need anything.

Regards

Comment: How about the round function? So that the output is equal to what OP wanted?!

Comment: Sure do @Rizier123 bro. thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($close); $i++) {
            $new[] = $close[$i] / $close[$i-1];
        }
    ?>
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: How about the round function? So that the output is equal to what OP wanted?!

Comment: <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($close); $i++) {
            $new[] = round($close[$i] / $close[$i-1], 2);
        }
    ?>